# My Wordpress site page scroll not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I created a page using the page builder. The content is not showing fully. Because I cannot scroll the page to see the whole page. There are 3-page codes I include in here. How to fix this error. Anyone can help me?

**my header-test.php page code**

```
<?php
/**
 * The header for our theme
 *
 * This is the template that displays all of the <head> section and everything up until <div id="content">
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#template-partials
 *
 * @package test
 */

?>
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="profile" href="https://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<?php wp_body_open(); ?>
<div id="page" class="site">
    <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#primary"><?php esc_html_e( 'Skip to content', 'test' ); ?></a>

    <header id="masthead" class="site-header">
        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
            <?php
            wp_nav_menu(
                array(
                    'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
                    'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
                )
            );
            ?>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
    </header><!-- #masthead -->
</div>
```

**my footer-test.php page code**

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer
 *
 * Contains the closing of the #content div and all content after.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#template-partials
 *
 * @package test
 */

?>

    <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer">
        <div class="site-info">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( __( 'https://wordpress.org/', 'test' ) ); ?>">
                <?php
                /* translators: %s: CMS name, i.e. WordPress. */
                printf( esc_html__( 'Proudly powered by %s', 'test' ), 'WordPress' );
                ?>
            </a>
            <span class="sep"> | </span>
                <?php
                /* translators: 1: Theme name, 2: Theme author. */
                printf( esc_html__( 'Theme: %1$s by %2$s.', 'test' ), 'test', '<a href="http://underscores.me/">Underscores.me</a>' );
                ?>
        </div><!-- .site-info -->
    </footer><!-- #colophon -->
</div><!-- #page -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my created customfullwidth.php  page code

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer
 *
 * Contains the closing of the #content div and all content after.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#template-partials
 *
 * @package test
 */

?>

    <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer">
        <div class="site-info">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( __( 'https://wordpress.org/', 'test' ) ); ?>">
                <?php
                /* translators: %s: CMS name, i.e. WordPress. */
                printf( esc_html__( 'Proudly powered by %s', 'test' ), 'WordPress' );
                ?>
            </a>
            <span class="sep"> | </span>
                <?php
                /* translators: 1: Theme name, 2: Theme author. */
                printf( esc_html__( 'Theme: %1$s by %2$s.', 'test' ), 'test', '<a href="http://underscores.me/">Underscores.me</a>' );
                ?>
        </div><!-- .site-info -->
    </footer><!-- #colophon -->
</div><!-- #page -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We need a [mcve] that would include your CSS and tendered HTML (not the PHP)

Comment: but friend my other pages working correctly, actually I need to change my design then I create new page template, new header & footer. then my content showing but it's not full page their content hiding and I can't scroll the page up